# How can I enter a literal <TAB> character in IntelliJ/IDEA/PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

My configuration indents with four spaces, and I want to keep that. Occasionally (e.g. in a Makefile) I want to input a literal TAB character.

How can I force the IntelliJ-IDEs to input a tab or space, when it would not do so when I hit tab or space in that instance?

Comment: If they're different types of files you could configure `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Tabs and Indents` for each one to use either space or tab depending on how you want it.

Answer (score 22):

You seem to be asking two questions here:

> *1. How do I force IntelliJ IDE to input a tab, when it would not do so when I hit tab?*

and

> *2. How do I force IntelliJ IDE to input a space, when it would not do so when I hit space?*

I don't understand how the second case can arise. However, I have provided a solution to it as well.

## Case 1. Insert a tab character when an IntelliJ IDE wants to replace it with spaces due to configuration

### Solution

Use search and replace.

### Details

1. Place the cursor where you want the tab to be
2. Press the `X` key
3. Select the `X` you just typed
4. From the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Replace to bring up the search and replace pane
5. Make sure there is an `X` in the search field
6. Enter `\t` in the replace field
7. Be sure the option `Regex` is checked
8. Be sure the option `In Selection` is checked
9. Click the `Replace` button

## Case 2. Insert a space character when an IntelliJ IDE won't just let you type one (???)

### Solution

Use search and replace.

### Details

1. Place the cursor where you want the space to be
2. Press the `X` key
3. Select the `X` you just typed
4. From the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Replace to bring up the search and replace pane
5. Make sure there is an `X` in the search field
6. Enter a single space into the replace field
7. Be sure the option `In Selection` is checked
8. Click the `Replace` button

Comment: Voting up because this is the easiest answer to remember and the fewest steps.  It is too bad the IDE has no escape for literal characters. Control-Q Tab will do it in emacs.

Answer (score 15):

Install the plugin for Makefile support: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9333-makefile-support

When I tried it today, this automatically use hard tabs in the editors for `Makefile` files.

Comment: this answer helped me

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. You should only use tabs when a particular syntax requires it and Makefiles are usually it, nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

Open another text editor, type a `tab`, and then copy and paste into the PyCharm editor.  In MacOSX this worked for me using both Sublime Text 2 and TextEdit.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; JetBrains always replaces the tab with four spaces :(

Comment: Apple Genius Bar!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any "direct" way. Probably the easiest way that I can think of is to write a Live Template to do it. See the [help page on Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/live-templates.html) for more information. When you write it, you may need to copy and paste a tab character in from another application.

However, when I tried it, IDEA saw it as just empty text and would not save it. So I used a variable with the "capitalize" function to capitalize a tab character.

[image: Screenshot of Live Template]

Here's the template I created that you can paste into your templates. Now I type `tab`, hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and I get a tab character.  Of course you can change the abbreviation.

```
<template name="tab" value="$TAB$" description="Enter a tab Character" toReformat="false" toShortenFQNames="true">
  <variable name="TAB" expression="capitalize(&quot;&#9;&quot;)" defaultValue="&#9;" alwaysStopAt="false" />
  <context>
    <option name="OTHER" value="true" />
  </context>
</template>
```

You could extend the idea to have multiple ones that enter multiple tabs. For example `tab` to enter 1 tab, `tab2` for 2 tabs, etc.

Screenshot of it after use:
[image: Screenshot of tabs used in code]

There may also be a way to hack a macro to do it. You could then assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut. I'll see if I can figure something out and update this if I do.

Comment: But if you have the `Code style -> Tabs and Indents` set to `space` (_Use tab character_ unchecked), will it not automatically replace the tab character?

Comment: No, not upon insertion. It differentiates between the inserting of a tab character and hitting the tab key. However, it will replace them on a code reformat, unless you use the `settings >  code style > "Formatter Control" > "Enable formatter markers in comments"` feature.  I've added a screenshot to my answer that shows two tabs I entered using the live template I created.

Comment: I still couldn't get the tab character to "take" using the UI but I stole your XML and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use the menu option: `Edit -> Convert Indents -> To Tabs`.

Whenever I edit a makefile I do the "to tabs" conversion before I save the file.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: Really sadly, I think the generated character still gets converted to spaces... Am checking...**

---

**There is an Action in JetBrains IDEs to enter a Tab character.**

Here are the steps to use the Tab character action: (discovered in PyCharm 2020.3)

1. Double-tap the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key OR **Help -> Find Action...**

[image]

2. **Type the 3 characters `tab`**
3. **Click on the action that is called `Tab`** and shows the icon for the Tab character...

[image]

---

It remembers the last action you did, so if you have several tabs to add, you can get into a quick process by doing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd> each time.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on @Morfic's comment to the question. I think this is the cleanest and most sensible reply here so I figured it deserves a place as an answer (and needless to say, it worked for me).

> If they're different types of files you could configure File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Tabs and Indents for each one to use either space or tab depending on how you want it.

Comment: This absolutely does NOT work for me. PyCharm 2019.3.3 (Community Edition). I've configured ALL file types to "Use tab character", but when I depress the 'tab' key, I get 4 spaces. This really sucks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to copy a TAB character from another text editor, then right click in your PyCharm file and use `Copy / Paste Special` -> `Paste as Plain Text` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

I guess this was not available in older PyCharm versions, because no other answer proposed it. Regular paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) doesn't work (replaced by spaces), but this one works. The function will also bypass other automatic formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired of Clare's suggestion,
assign the left tab key after finding 'tab' action.

At Actions tab, search by 'tab' and move your up/down arrow key and place there.
Then type Ctrl+1, you will see a popup. Select as follows and click OK.

[image]

Then, you might be asked "Do you want to remove other assignments?" if Tab key was already assigned. Click Leave because your usage won't conflict with the existing setup.